# How to tell gradle to install npm within the project on build?

Tags: java, angular, gradle, npm-install

My angular 4 UI for a java web application depends only on the below few bundles. I ran the below commands from webapps root. App works fine. I want to know the best practices as I'm new to angular.

```
npm install rxjs
npm install @angular/core@4.4.6 @angular/common@4.4.6 @angular/compiler@4.4.6 @angular/platform-browser@4.4.6 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.4.6 @angular/router@4.4.6 @angular/forms@4.4.6 --save
npm install typescript@2.4.2 --save
npm install plugin-typescript@5.2.7 --save
```

I'm referring the installed bundles from `systemjs.config.js` like below:

```
paths: {
       'npm:' : 'node_modules/'
},
map: {
       '@angular/core' : 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js'
       .
       .
}
```

**Queries:**

1. The app should not be heavy, could not include the entire `node_modules` in `war`
2. If I keep `node_modules` in project root instead of webapps, how do I refer it from `systemjs.config.js`
3. I just want those bundles and not the huge file stack that gets downloaded while running `npm install @angular/cli`
4. If we can use global `node_modules`, how to refer to that from `systemjs.config.js` (I prefer keeping it within project not to disturb other applications in the server using different versions)
5. Finally, what should I include in `build.gradle` to download the required bundles while gradle builds

Comment: Gradle doesn't have native understanding of the JS ecosystem.  You can try e.g. the [gradle-node-plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin), but it's a bit limited, in my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Oliver Charlesworth said, Gradle has his limitations, but you can create a custom gradle task.

Example:

```
task npmInstall(type: Exec) {
    workingDir 'src/main/webapp'
    commandLine 'npm', 'install'
}
```

Add the build dependency to your `war` build step

```
war {
    dependsOn npmBuild
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is it's going to run `npm install` every time.  So ideally you want to find some way to denote when the task is up to date.

Comment: You are right, but the dependencies will be downloaded once, so only the first time the task consumes some time.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim Hovius says: you can create your own task.

If you don't want it to execute all the time, you can add the OnlyIf clause.

(From the official documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:onlyIf(groovy.lang.Closure)

```
myTask.onlyIf(new Spec<Task>() {
    boolean isSatisfiedBy(Task task) {
        return isProductionEnvironment();
    }
});
```

OR

You can write the task more intelligently using standard Groovy.
For example:

```
task doSomething {
    doLast {
        def file = new File("dummy.txt")

        if (file.exists()) {
            project.exec {
                commandLine 'someCommand', 'parameter'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OR

In your build.gradle for example

```
task doSomething {
   doLast {
        ...
   }
}

doSomething.enabled = (some condition goes here)
```